# Some POSTS stopped working after upgrading Newtonsoft.JSON to v10

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net, owin

**Update 1**: I disabled SSL and still have the issue. So, it probably had to do with upgrading OWIN.

**Update 2**: I started from scratch and figured out what causes the break. It is upgrading Newstonsoft.JSON from 6.0.4 to 10.0.1 (the latest version 12.0.3 also causes the break). It is a dependency for Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.

I am using ASP.NET 4.5.2.

I was trying to get external logins working on my site, and I found that to do that I had to upgrade OWIN to the latest version, and set SSL Enabled to 'true'. I got the external logins working, but in doing so I think I broke my site.

Everything works fine except for certain POSTS. By inspection, it looks like the requests that are breaking are the ones that are larger (~3KB).

I have inspected the requests with Fiddler, and see that they're being sent fine. However, when they hit the Controller, the `model` parameter is set to `null`.

Here is a sample of the breaking code:

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Calculation/calcProject")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post_CalcProject(ProjectViewModel model)
    {
        return InvokeOfBS<ProjectViewModel, ProjectResultModel>(_calculationBMS.CalcProject, model);
    }
```

The parameter `model` is a `ProjectViewModel`, but it's getting set to `null`.

As an experiment, I changed the `model` parameter to a `TotalProjectCostViewModel`, which has many fewer fields than a `ProjectViewModel`. Interestingly, `model` was not set to `null`. Instead, it was an empty `TotalProjectCostViewModel` (which makes sense, because the request JSON was not made for that model).

This is the POST code (TypeScript):

```
  calcProject(model: ProjectViewModel): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post('/api/Calculation/calcProject', model, options)
            .map(this.extractDataPost).catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Comment: Please include your POST call as well along with the c# code.

Comment: _"I have inspected the requests with Fiddler, and see that they're being sent fine. However, when they hit the Controller, the model parameter is set to null"_ - so probably this has nothing to do with OWIN or SSL. Can you easily revert to a state before introducing that change and verifying the same request works? Also, which MVC version do you use?

Comment: I'd suggest that model binding fails because of JSON issues. Your payload probably doesn't match your model exactly. On Fiddler's Composer tab, create a new request and trim the JSON until it works. When you found what particular part of the JSON broke it, you can [edit] your question and include only the relevant JSON and class definition of `ProjectViewModel`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Targeting ASP.NET 4.5.2. Does that tell you the MVC version.

Comment: @CodeCaster Maybe you're right. But I didn't change the model at all, and it's been working fine for months.

Comment: @CodeCaster Also, how come when I did my "experiment" I got an empty model instead of null?

Comment: I can't tell, because you don't show what your request and your model look like.

Comment: @CodeCaster I went into the Composer tab and took out every single attribute from the model except for one, but I'm still getting the same error. The model has about 100 fields, so I can't really do trial and error.